# How to build a web3 mobile dapp with react native

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, ethereum-wallet-dapp, frontend

For weeks now i have been trying to building to mobile dapps for web3 but all has failed, is it possible to build web3 mobile dapp on the evm. i would love to hear from you guys on how to go about that.

Comment: I don't have suggestions, I just wanna wish you all the best with your game.

Comment: it would be more useful to know what specific problems you're facing. the question is too vague to get an answer